# The name 'Parquet.Document' doesn't exist in the current context error message

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am seeing this **(64, 16)-(64, 32) The name 'Parquet.Document' doesn't exist in the current context** error message.

I am using PowerBI Desktop 64-bit May 2020, version 2.81.5831.1181, on a Windows 10 Enterprise machine.

Limitations:

(a) Upgrading to a newer version of Desktop is not an option as the Report Server does not support newer version.

I had accidently tried that anyway with May 2023 version (or later, don't recall the exact 2023 version) as I had installed the latest version at the time.  When I discovered that the server didn't support it, I downgraded to May 2020.  When I received the above error message, I tried Sept 2020 version but the server did not support that either.

(b) Upgrading the report server is also not an option. (Management decision.)

The steps to reproduce the error is the following:

1. Create a new PowerBI file.
2. Click Get Data --> Select SQL Server database --> click Connect
3. Specify Server.  Specify Database. Specify DirectQuery.  Specify a SQL statement.  Click Ok.
4. Data preview pops up.  Click Load.
5. The above noted (64, 16)-(64, 32) The name 'Parquet.Document' doesn't exist in the current context error message pops up.

I have uninstalled and then reinstalled Desktop (May 2020) a couple of times but the error remains and prevents the creation of any new PowerBI desktop files.

I've also tried opening existing (previously created) PowerBI files.

Any PowerBI file that was set up as DirectQuery will not open as the above error message is generated instead.

I can open PowerBI files set up as Import.  I can even make changes to the existing queries.  However, when I click on Edit Queries, and then click Data source settings, the same error message is generated again.

So it appears that PowerBI Desktop is no longer allowing me to create new queries.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.